# What are the APIs used by SQL Profiler?

Tags: sql-server, api, sql-server-profiler

SQL Server Profiler displays a live stream of commands being executed against a SQL server instance. What are the APIs used to capture this data?

Background: I need to write a small utility (in C++) which tracks the SQL commands being issued by a separate application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here on the [API Development Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/26/Receiving-Profiler-Events.aspx) is a quick C# (should be easy to convert to c++) program which connects to SQL Server and shows the text of all starting batches in real time as the requests are coming to SQL Server.

e.g. Code snippet from link

```
Console.WriteLine("Event : " + trace["EventClass"]);
Console.WriteLine("SPID  : " + trace["SPID"]);
Console.WriteLine("Login : " + trace["SessionLoginName"]);
Console.WriteLine("Object: " + trace["ObjectName"]);
Console.WriteLine("Text  : " + trace["TextData"]);
```

As Alex mentioned, you will need to use the **TraceServer** API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is how Profiler does it, but they are exposed via the [TraceServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345134%28SQL.90%29.aspx#sqltrc_topic2) API.

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](http://yongslee.wordpress.com/2010/02/18/starting-sql-trace-using-c/) explains about Trae Management Object (TMO) and how to use it.

A handy profiler tool using this TMO can be found at [HERE](http://www.sqlmgmt.com/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=104)