# How to intercept SQL traffic client side

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to log all SQL that a client app is sending to a remote SQL server I have no access to.  I'm thinking of some kind of client side proxy that can log and pass through data.  It has to run on the same machine as the client app.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's protocol, TDS ("Tabular Data Stream") is not encrypted by default, so a trivial packet-forwarder could be used to proxy SQL Server connections and intercept commands (and their responses).

The TDS protocol specification is available from Microsoft's website, you could write your own proxy which can intercept commands that way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

However, this is a large undertaking. You have other simpler options if you don't need to capture every connection:

- If you control your application's source-code, then simply modify all database operations to intercept every `SqlCommand`'s `CommandText` and `Parameter` values.
- You could skip writing a proxy and instead use native packet-capture, you'll need to use `WinPCap`: https://www.winpcap.org/
- You could also use SQL Server's Profiling features to get a log of every command executed: [What are the APIs used by SQL Profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719909/what-are-the-apis-used-by-sql-profiler)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is called an `SQL Profiler`.
In specific - you are looking for an API for one.

I have never used an API of a profiler myself - but [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2006/05/25/programmatically-receiving-profiler-events-in-real-time-from-sql-server-2005/) looks promising.
Also - take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719909/what-are-the-apis-used-by-sql-profiler) question for another sample.

If you want to have an impression of a working profiler client you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118521/how-to-see-sql-query-in-sql-profiler#21191817) answer.