# Get sql statements from an exe (no source code)

Tags: sql-server, profiler, sql-server-profiler

I have an exe written in Delphi a decade or more ago, with no source code. It calls a ms sql database, maybe more than 1 to retrieve data. I have read only access to one of the databases, I don't have rights to run sql profiler on it.

Is there a way to get the sql calls that are being made like how fiddler does it for http requests. I'm hoping that there is an app that I can run.

Thank you.

Comment: Nope, if you don't have access to create a Extended Event, or similar, to capture the statements being run you'll have no idea. You'll need to speak to someone who does have that access. If *anyone* could access the statements being run against an instance, that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: Run a trace (Profiler or Extended Events) on the SQL Server including `batch_completed` and `rpc_completed` events. Best to do that in a test system.

Comment: Create an environment where you have the necessary privileges to run the profiler, make a copy of your database in that environment and let your application target that testenvironment ...

Comment: @Larnu is there no application I can install on the computer that runs the exe to catch the network traffic and see the statement.

Comment: Yes, Profiler and Extended Events do that, @David ; you just need the permissions to set them up. Like I said, if *anyone* could just intercept the SQL statements from an application it would be a massive security risk.

Comment: @David, the trace runs on the SQL Server, not the client. Trace data are viewed using a client tool (Profiler or SSMS Extended Events).

Comment: Do you have WSL installed in Windows? `man strings`

Comment: [How to intercept SQL traffic client side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41541125/15498). There still aren't any simple answers I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of Delphi store string properties inside the executable file, at the end of the file.
If the developers did not take action to obscure this, than chances are you can retrieve them there.

It is not always easy to read though, I opened an old delphi program here and searched for the text "select distinct" and this is what came up

[image]

some more queries I found, they are there but as I said, not easy to read.

[image]